# Android HttpEntity to consume content

Tags: android

I am using Android API 21, I can't use 22, and I am trying to figure out which HTTPEntity will properly consumeContent(). Most of the implementations of HttpEntity say that they don't actaully consume content so how can I do this? Is it just not possible in Android to consume content before API 22?

Comment: 1. `I am using Android API 21, I can't use 22`. Always target the latest API. 2. `Most of the implementations of HttpEntity say that they don't actaully consume content so how can I do this` Who says this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I can't target the latest API as I said above. and as for the consuming content I am going off the Android dev site which for BasicHttpEntity, ByteArrayEntity,InputStreamEntity and AbstractHttpEntity all say the same thing.

   "consumeContent()
    Does not consume anything."

Comment: `I can't target the latest API` That does not make any sense. Also, you should try using Square's Retrofit or Pivotal's Android Spring REST template.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I started with someone else's code. It's about 50,000 lines and trying to switch to the latest API makes a good portion error. It's one of the joys of Android switching to open connection.....